# Eclipse projects (available in directory) are not visible in the Package Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

Today when I started Eclipse (using same workspace), the package explorer view is not showing any project, even though the projects are there in the directory (workspace).

To solve this problem, I created fresh new workspace and tried to import same project to this new location but with no success. Clicking on the finish button does not do anything.

Kindly help. What should I do now?

Comment: check project(s) has .project file in it. Also check .log file in <workspace>/.metadata for any errors

Comment: I think Eclipse Bundle set up was corrupted. So I installed new Bundle and created new workspace and copied every project to this new workspace. Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Do this, in either the Project Explorer, Java, Java EE or the Enterprise Explorer view. In the view, click the little down-arrow to open a menu, and choose Deselect Working Set. This worked for me, and my project that was already there that wasn’t showing up now shows up